# Can I repurchase apps so they can be shared with my family library?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-family

The documentation states:

> Any apps or games purchased after July 2, 2016 are eligible to be added to Family Library. If you purchased the app or game before July 2, 2016, it’s eligible for Family Library if the developer has made past purchases available. You can find out whether this is the case by tapping Read More on the app’s details page.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7007852

I have apps that I purchased before this cut off date that I would like to share via my Family Library.  Unfortunately when I visit the Play Store page for these apps I am offered either an `Install` or `Uninstall` button instead of the `Buy` button.

This leads me to ask:

- Am I able to repurchase these apps with my primary google account so that  I can share them via the Family Library?
- If I purchase them with a Family Linked child account will they be shared with the other members of our Family?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**

The solution I have found is to purchase the software with another family member's account and from there set the Family Library toggle to true.

This can be done from a child account with the caveat that parental permission will be required if their account has been configured with that option.